# Having issues with shell script concept

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

> Hi, I have a file with following contents

```
> 1234 alphabet /vag/one/arun  
> 1454 bigdata /home/two/ogra  
> 5684 apple /vinay/three/dire
```

> but i want the output to be like

```
> 1234 alphabet one  
> 1454 bigdata two  
> 5684 apple three
```

Comment: Wonderful.  So what is your question?  And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{
  split($NF,ar,"/");
  $NF=ar[3]
  for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    printf "%s ",$i
  }
  printf "\n"
}' filename
```

Take the last field delimited by space and split it into the array ar based on "/", the last field equal to the third element in ar and then loop through the fields printing them.

Comment: Thanks lot sir but can i do this with nested loops like while,for etc. Can you help me with that

Comment: @ricky: Apart from the fact that the awk solution **is** a nested loop, I'm wondering: What makes you being so much in love with nested loops that you dislike programs which don't have one?

Answer (score 0):

Cut each input line into pieces, throw the parts you don't need into a wastebasket, and reassemble what is left. For instance:

```
grep -Eo '(^|/[^/]+/|/[^/]+$|[^/]+)' <INPUTFILE| grep -Fv /|xargs -L 2 -d '\n' echo >OUTPUTFILE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by controlling `IFS` (the *Internal Field Separator*) which when it includes the `'/'` character will cause *filed splitting* to occur allowing you to read `a/b/c` into separate variables. Then it's just a matter of printing the variables you want, e.g. with your original contents in `file`,

```
$ while IFS="${IFS}/" read -r n l a b c; do echo "$n $l $b"; done < file
1234 alphabet one
1454 bigdata two
5684 apple three
```